# How to make a xml-RPC call from OpenERP to a JavaServer?

Tags: java, python, odoo, xml-rpc

I am new to OpenERP and playing around.
My plan is to connect OpenERP to a SOAP Webservice. Hence, OpenERP does only support XML-RPC I will write a converter in Java. I am able to make a call from Java to OpenERP but I do not know how I should start with the other direction.

My goal is to change the Manufacturing Workflow. After "Confirm Production" it should send some data via XML-RPC to my Java xmlrpc Server.

I created a new node and add a Server Action with the following code:

```
import xmlrpclib

sock = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8080/xmlrpctest/xmlrpc')
```

This gives me the error
NameError: name 'xmlrpclib' is not defined

I thought the xmlrpclib is always included in OpenERP.

I would be glad if somebody could tell what the right approach is to call from OpenERP over XML-RPC a java server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doing XML-RPC from OpenERP would be easy - you have Python libraries for that. What you need is to understand the OpenERP structure and to imagine for yourself how exactly your action will be executed. If you already decided that this will happen trough `server action` then read this: https://doc.openerp.com/6.0/developer/4_13_server_action/ if you didn't. After that edit your question to give more details of what exactly you did right now.

Comment: I dont get it at all! I searched the web the whole day! It seems to me nobody wants to call a xmlrpc server out of OpenERP. There are just tutorials how to connect into OpenERP. What do i wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As Andrei says, this isn't an OpenERP question, this is just a general python question.  You will need to look at the python SOAP libraries to make SOAP calls to your java web-service.

As a caution though, think carefully about hooking the SOAP call into the workflow as you will get all your transactions failing in OpenERP if the java server is down.  Unless you need them to be synchronous would be better to use a queue (Celery, Rabbit etc) and just dump the message into the queue.  You can use the OpenERP scheduled tasks to kick of a synchronise process when you need.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it in a server action. You can read in the OpenERP documentation (the link I already sent you :)) the following

> The code is executed using the exec function of python, which is run in the dictionary namespace with variables: object,time,cr,uid,ids

Well, I think that's not completely true - actions in OpenERP are executed trough the `tools.safe_eval.safe_eval()` method. From the doc string of this method:

> ```
> """safe_eval(expression[, globals[, locals[, mode[, nocopy]]]]) -> result
>
> System-restricted Python expression evaluation
>
> Evaluates a string that contains an expression that mostly
> uses Python constants, arithmetic expressions and the
> objects directly provided in context.
>
> This can be used to e.g. evaluate
> an OpenERP domain expression from an untrusted source.
>
> Throws TypeError, SyntaxError or ValueError (not allowed) accordingly.
> ```

Without entering in the details, it's a restricted execution. Instead of this do the following:

1. Create your own module
2. Create a class which inherits from `mrp.production`. I mean, do

   `_inherit = 'mrp.production'`

   inside your class.
3. Override in this class the method executed after "Confirm Production" (whatever this is).
4. Do what you need with your rpc server in this new method.
5. Don't forget to call `super()`

Answer (score 1):

'xmlrpclib' was introduced into the Python standard library at Python 2.2, and in version 3.0 was renamed to 'xmlrpc' and reorganised.